# How to use subprocess.run method in python?

Tags: python

I wanted to run external programs using python but I receive an error saying I don't have the file

the code I wrote:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hahan\desktop\Pythonp\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
  File "C:\Users\hahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\hahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\hahan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I expected it to return the files in that directory

Comment: What happens if you type "ls -l" on the command line? Do you have an `"ls" command on your Windows machine? Its commonly available on linux and mac. I'm not sure about the latest windows, but historically, its only been available in windows with external packages.

Comment: IIRC, Windows doesn't have an `ls` command (except for PowerShell, where it's actually an alias for `Get-ChildItem`), so did you install one? If you did, is it in the `PATH`?

Comment: `dir` may work if you set `shell=True`. `ls` and `dir` are fine for examples, but one would use the python equivalent `os.listdir` or maybe `glob.glob` or something in the `pathlib` module. You could try some known .exe on your system if you are just experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace suggests you're using Windows as the operating system. `ls` not something that you will typically find on a Windows machine unless using something like CygWin.

Instead, try one of these options:

```py
# use python's standard library function instead of invoking a subprocess
import os
os.listdir()
```

```py
# invoke cmd and call the `dir` command
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["cmd", "/c", "dir"])
```

```py
# invoke PowerShell and call the `ls` command, which is actually an alias for `Get-ChildItem`
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-c", "ls"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls` is not a Windows command. The windows analogue is `dir`, so you could do something like

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cmd', '/c', 'dir'])
```

However, if you're really just trying to list a directory it would be much better (and portable) to use something like [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir)

```
from pathlib import Path
list(Path().iterdir())
```